# slack api to find existing channel

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am playing with slack apis to create an integration. I am able to sucessfully create a slack channel using

```
 this.http.post(slackApiHost + '/channels.create', payload, {headers: headers})
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    resolve(res)
                },
                err => {
                    console.log('error:' + err)
                }
                )
        })
```

the payload looks like

```
var payload = {
        "name" : channelName
    };
```

So, it will fail with name_taken if the channel already exists. which is great. However, I need to find the channel id of the existing channel so that i can then use it for my purpose. how do i go about it?

Comment: Is this information useful for you? https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list This was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: no this list all. i m looking ot search a specfic by name

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I had thought that the existence of channel and the channel name and ID can be retrieved using the channel list retrieved from this API. From your comment, I could understand that this way is not what you want. I'm really sorry for my incomplete proposal.

Answer (score 9):

To get a list of all existing channel you can use [`conversations.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list). This is the most flexible approach and allows you to retrieve any type of channel if you so choose.

If you are looking for a channel by a specific name you will need to first retrieve the list of all channels and then run your own name matching against the full list. An API method which allows you to directly search for a channel by name does not exist.

Note that if you are looking for private channels this method will only retrieve channels that you (the installer of your Slack app / your bot user) has been invited to.

Comment: well. As I said, that is the only available approach for your problem. There is no other / "more performant" approach.

Comment: Well that's a real shame

Comment: Interestingly, when using the Slack web client, I see that there is a channel search API via https://edgeapi.slack.com/cache/TMQ5151S9/channels/search (when checking the network in the dev toolbar), but it doesn't seem to be "publicly available" (no way to properly retrieve/renew the necessary access token) nor documented.

Comment: It's 2022 and still can't filter this endpoint. We have to sync the channels to our own database and search through them since the pagination + string matching strategy suggested as a different answer to this question is risky due to rate-limiting.

Comment: There is a method available for search(https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.conversations.search). API requires token of an admin user. But it seems like this can be used only by Enterprise Grid organization. Guessing it is like a premium paid workspace.

Answer (score 6):

There's currently no direct Slack API to find a slack channel by its name. But you can use [conversations.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list) to handle this and here's the right code to use:

```
const slack = new SlackWebClient(token);
const channelNameToFind = "test";

for await (const page of slack.paginate("conversations.list", {
  limit: 50,
})) {
  for (const channel of page.channels) {
    if (channel.name === channelNameToFind) {
      console.log(`Found ${channelNameToFind} with slack id ${channel.id}`);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the right way™️ to do it since it will ensure you stop listing channels as soon as you found the right one.

Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't work for large organizations with tens of thousands of channels.

Comment: Just to add context to the above comment, this fails because this is a tier 2 rate limited endpoint. At my company, it would take 15 to 20 minutes to paginate through all channels due to rate limits.

Answer (score 4):

You can use built-in [admin.conversations.search](https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.conversations.search)
and then iterate found results.

One more kind of **fast tricky solution**:
try to send [chat.scheduleMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.scheduleMessage) and then if it was sent [chat.deleteScheduledMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.deleteScheduledMessage) or catch error.
Ruby example:

```
def channel_exists?(channel)
  begin
    response = @slack_client.chat_scheduleMessage(channel: channel, text: '', post_at: Time.now.to_i + 100)
    @slack_client.chat_deleteScheduledMessage(channel: channel, scheduled_message_id: response.scheduled_message_id)
    return true
  rescue Slack::Web::Api::Errors::ChannelNotFound
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked for me, definitely a work-around but works great, thanks!